# Is flagging or VTCing more appropriate for const *iption questions?

Tags: discussion, flagging, const-iption-trolling, down-votes, vote-to-close

In addition to downvoting const *iption questions, should I flag and/or VTC them?

Comment: ...are there new ones we missed? or did the stuff end... for the moment?

Comment: Are you kidding? They should be nuked from orbit within milliseconds of being posted. All other conduct feeds the troll. It's the same with graffiti on a wall, if it continuously and without fail gets blanked within hours, the kids will eventually get wise and stop wasting paint. But honestly since YOU someone are posting as many questions as the original miscreant... well. It leads a person to suspect your true role in this.

Comment: Given the trollish nature of such questions, I would flag them as *rude or abusive*.

Answer (score 8):

VTC doesn't hurt; but definitely flag so we can destroy the account that posted along with the post itself.

Comment: should we dupe-link them too?

Comment: @Trish – shouldn't matter since as soon as a mod gets the flag the post should be deleted.